# Omit specific prop from an emotion styled component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components, emotion

I have a `BoxWithAs` component, defined something like this:

```
const BoxWithAs = styled.div(
  {
    WebkitFontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
    MozOsxFontSmoothing: 'grayscale'
    // And more …
  }
);
```

All fine, but now I want to deprecate one of the default props coming from `@emotion/styled`, specifically the `as` prop.

I did this:

```
type BoxWithAsType = typeof BoxWithAs;
type BoxProps = Omit<React.ComponentProps<BoxWithAsType>, 'as'>;

/**
 * Component that does it all.
 */
const Box = (props: BoxProps) => {
  return <BoxWithAs {...props}>{props.children}</BoxWithAs>;
};
```

It does remove the prop ...

[image]

... but now the component itself looses all its `StyledComponent` typing information.

[image]

How can I structure this so I achieve both? My end goal is to deprecate the `as` prop, and rather encourage the usage of `.withComponent` (for Typescript reasons).

Comment: can you please add a sandbox env? less guess-work, more answers :)

Comment: So you want to use `withComponent` which is slated for deprecation in favor of `as` just for "typescript reasons"? You want to go in the inverse direction of your dependency for typescript?

Comment: `React.ComponentProps<BoxWithAsType> & { as: never }` should work fine?

Comment: @kellys That will loose all the typings coming from `@emotion/styled`.

Comment: I'm a bit confused now; how is `Box` supposed to have a `withComponent` method? It's just a function.

Comment: @kellys `as=""` can't infer correct types. E.g. `<Box as="img" src="/img" />` throw error, since `src` is not a property on div. While `Box.withComponent('img')` actually returns a new component with correct types for an img element.

Comment: [This](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAZxgTwDYFMAmcBmUIhwBEAAuiBDMBAHYD0SaWRA3AFCiSxwBK6AhgGN4eAsSgDhrNm0G0kcAEIQAHgHVgMABYBBBHAC8iFBkwA6TMABuACgDeMgL4BKGSjDolqjdr0AVZA9DOHd0CBwvdU1dBHZQyIAFfDB9IwB5EE0AHj4hGDMAYQJIGnQaGCSIFKzlKN8EAI8APgAaOAByfgR2pvY2OgAqAbY4Abgi8Foy+G1+eEwIdH1NOH5UVDMRgbpZeXha4JswZIQALl5JfImS6crq2p8YxvQm50MmuAc4OAkYAFcoDQ4DVvNE9J8zJDjlUEI4mnZoSkzIItMBUJgJDRHFk6A8wQhemxHH1amYAO7Ra5TcpAA) demonstrates on what I'm confused about. Even with the normal props it doesn't have a `withComponent` method so why would there be a `withComponent` method without `as`?

Comment: That is my question though. How can a create a custom component that has the same type/props as `BoxWithAs`, except without the `as` prop (but still with the `.withComponent()` function. This works: `const Example = BoxWithAs.withComponent('img')` but I wan't to disable the as prop.

Comment: Alternative question is how to fix this type issue: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAZxgTwDYFMAmcBmUIhwBEAAuiBDMBAHYD0SaWRA3AFCiSxwBK6AhgGN4eAsSgDhrNm0G0kcAEIQAHgHVgMABYBBBHAC8iFBkwA6TMABuACgDeMgL4BKGXJoKAoiv7gMhpVUNbT0zAHdNLQBhAkgadBoYGwByUABzZNc2FDB0QPVIvQAVZFyAnPQIHHzg3QR2CvyABXwwfSMAeRBNAB4+IRgzGPBaBJgWiDae5QKQhBLcgD4AGjhk-gRkxfY2OgAqPbY4PbhhuLG4bX54TAh0fU04flRUMyO9ull5eBmAmzBWggAFy8SSDM6jRITKYzWrFUroRbOQyLOAOOBwCQwACuUBocGmQUK+jsZjJAMmCEcizsFLaZkEWmAqEwEhojh6dFhxO2bEcO12BzgAAkOmpLhBcMAVJcmQgAPzHT6EmUbAxEdJERBQQTquhauiLNhAA

Comment: You might want to edit the question to make that clearer then.

Comment: @eivindml I don't think there is a better way than [this](https://tsplay.dev/wOPrlN).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we hover over `BoxWithAs` we see that it is of this type:

```
StyledComponent<{
    theme?: Theme | undefined;
    as?: React.ElementType<any> | undefined;
}, React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>, {}>
```

So you could do:

```
type BoxWithoutAs = StyledComponent<{
    theme?: Theme | undefined;
}, React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>, {}>;

const Box = BoxWithAs as BoxWithoutAs;
```

But that type is really long and unwieldy. We try simplifying it and making it a little drier:

```
StyledComponent<Omit<React.ComponentProps<BoxWithAsType>, "as">, React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>, {}>
```

That's not much better and arguably worse. What would help is if we could infer the other two parameters instead of having us typing it in full.

We can make use of a helper utility type:

```
type OmitProps<Component, Props extends PropertyKey> = Component extends StyledComponent<infer P, infer S, infer J> ? StyledComponent<Omit<P, Props>, S, J> : never;
```

Now, TypeScript will infer the other two parameters for us, and we can use `Omit<P, Props>` to omit any props we wish.

```
const Box = BoxWithAs as OmitProps<BoxWithAsType, "as">;
```

Seems to work fine!

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAZxgTwDYFMAmAaOBvOAZRQ0wGEJwIA7da+AXzgDMpK4AiAAXRAhmA0A9EjRYOAbgBQoSLDgAldAEMAxvFbsOUFeslSpqmkjgAhCAA8A6sBgALAIII4AXkQksAOkzAAbgAo8AwYASmkpFDB0M0sbeycAFWQo1zhI9AhmGOtbRwRw9LgAeRBbAAU2MAQAHgoqWnpcCogquHQLGDpMZ2ao2GQAaXRkAD5UusgG+HbO6m6iD3JKSboYauBqZnQoODLcDa2dwn3N7bgAKTGAfgWxJfrV6pLbar3dyoQR3GOLsYAuOC0XzbcJGagmcwWVKQuJ5ODKZzPGC9Gow3KJZLoXAcBEcEbhaqQ+EIFwcUAAcw4iCgqlJQipQhGUiAA)

Comment: This is a perfect example of why the industry should immediately turn it's back on Typescript. What a mess and for what?

Comment: This is why we shouldn't use JavaScript. It's such a mess with dynamic typing and quirks people commonly exploit to write shorter but less intention-explicit code. This and for what? A website? Let's all use languages that compile to WASM instead.

Comment: @morganney I wouldn't want to start an argument but is this not cherry picking on the cases that TypeScript gets verbose (this is nowhere as verbose it can get)? Why not see all the good it can do as well? Anyways, it's more of a preference. Besides, if your work requires it, might as well get with the program.

Comment: I don't know man I spent less than 5 minutes total writing up this answer. To me TypeScript is a great trade of some time for type safety in JavaScript. And when you're really proficient in utilizing the type system it's just smoother than glass.

Comment: I do not believe for one second that you took less than five minutes, lol.

Comment: I suppose when you look at the timestamps it looks like 50 but I actually spent 45 on doing other work. Admittedly I don't know much about the work force as I'm just a high schooler doing Stack Overflow instead of schoolwork. Though I agree that TypeScript can get verbose fairly quickly and that it's mostly hype, it's still a tool I'd still like to use. Like any other tool, you spend time to learn it, then you save more time with it later on.